# Switching from polling to event based system

Tags: c++, multithreading

Basically what i am trying to achieve is to check whether the data has been changed or not since the last time i checked.

What i am doing here is i initiate a separate thread that continuously runs in a loop and checks the stop variable at the end of the loop. The stop variable is a global variable so i can easily give it a 0 value to terminate the polling loop from the main thread.

In the loop i have a set of variables that hold the value of data that i retrieved in the previous iteration and a set of variables that are used to store the recently retrieved data. All i do is compare the variable with the new data with the ones that are holding the previous data. After this i update the set of variables that are holding the previous data to the most recent data.

I wanted to ask if there is a more efficient way of doing this? maybe something that would not require polling?

Comment: Yes, of course there is a better solution. You name it in the title: an event-based system. When the data is modified, an event is raised. All interested parties subscribe to that event and thus receive a notification.

Comment: To add: In windows there is CreateEvent, SetEvent, ... WaitForSingleObject. That can be used to signal a value change. For standard C++ similar functionality can be created by using atomics, mutex and/or condition variables.

Answer (score 2):

Yes; one way is to have the polling thread wait on a condition variable, and have the producer wake it up by signalling the same condition variable.

An example in C++ is given at [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/condition_variable):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <thread>
#include <mutex>
#include <condition_variable>

std::mutex m;
std::condition_variable cv;
std::string data;
bool ready = false;
bool processed = false;

void worker_thread()
{
    // Wait until main() sends data
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lk(m);
    cv.wait(lk, []{return ready;});

    // after the wait, we own the lock.
    std::cout << "Worker thread is processing data\n";
    data += " after processing";

    // Send data back to main()
    processed = true;
    std::cout << "Worker thread signals data processing completed\n";

    // Manual unlocking is done before notifying, to avoid waking up
    // the waiting thread only to block again (see notify_one for details)
    lk.unlock();
    cv.notify_one();
}

int main()
{
    std::thread worker(worker_thread);

    data = "Example data";
    // send data to the worker thread
    {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lk(m);
        ready = true;
        std::cout << "main() signals data ready for processing\n";
    }
    cv.notify_one();

    // wait for the worker
    {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lk(m);
        cv.wait(lk, []{return processed;});
    }
    std::cout << "Back in main(), data = " << data << '\n';

    worker.join();
}
```